# Is an improperly configured HTTPS site inherently more dangerous than plain HTTP?

Tags: tls, firefox

I'm on Firefox 54, and I noticed a site with a bad HTTPS configuration sometimes gets a large warning page, while there is not any such page yet for plain HTTP.

Comment: This will change in the future, browsers will start to flag unprotected sites with warnings. They already start to do that for unprotected forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An improper TLS connection could be a positive signal that a middleman is interfering with the connection.

Imagine if you got a letter supposedly from a friend, but then at the end it was signed with someone else's name. If the letter wasn't signed, you probably would have trusted the letter, but the fact that it has someone else's signature is extremely worrying.